# Detect two finger touch and zoom out image

Tags: android

Good Day, I'm newbie in android, and I would like to add one functionality to my app, but I haven't idea how to do that.

I would like to `Zoom Out` image by [Two-finger touch](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/gestures.html#gestures-touch-mechanics)

I had implemented `Zoom In` functionality using [Subsampling Scale Image View library](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view), but how to add `Zoom Out` I don't know.

What I have for now? What I must to add under the `Toast` to get `ImageView` normal state?

```
 ImageView mImageView;
mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        int action = motionEvent.getAction();
        int fingersCount = motionEvent.getPointerCount();
        if((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) && (fingersCount == 2)){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Double tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: A good library that will do this for you is called PhotoView: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView . It's incredibly easy to implement.

Comment: @ariets this library hasn`t that functionality. I need zoomOut by two-finger touch

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood (assumed two finger touch was more pinch to zoom out).